# WriteableBitmap vs. BitmapImage What to use?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am developing a Photo Gallery application for WinRT and I do not know what to use.

What is better to use?
Is it better to use instances of `BitmapImage` or `WriteableBitmap`?
What are pros and cons of each?

Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There are some memory collection issues with `WriteableBitmap` - however you might use it to display pictures with alpha channel (like png format). `BitmapImage` is ideal for `jpg`, but I have encountered problems with setting big stream source with asynchronous `SetSourceAsync` so if you'll get any issues with that - use synchronous version instead. Also worth mention if you want to clear `BitmapImage` memory - set `BitmapImage` source to empty stream (let it be `InMemoryRandomAccessStream` - memory leak free solution)

Comment: I know about issues.
I chceck this in Performance monitor but i do not know if is normal when i load image aprox. 10 000x5000 px system consumes about 430MB RAM, After image is rendered consumption is decreased to about half.
Because sometimes image is rendered and sometimes not i use scale to smaller resolution about 50% and consuumption is in both decreased byu aprox 50%.
Is this normal to consume 4 hundred MB of ram ? I use WriteableBitmap

Comment: I guess that's normal. First I suggest you: use Nokia Imaging SDK with JPEGRender (low memory consumption as image is rendered as JPG), second don't bother with full image rendering (only if you want to save or smth) - scale it to display dimension - can be done easily with Nokia Imaging SDK. If you don't want to use Nokia Imaging SDK - use BitmapImage and set DecodePixelWidth/DecodePixelHeight to screen dimension.

Comment: I hope Nokia SDK supports Windows store apps. And i thought that maybe is better to render image scaled to display dimensions, but i did not know if it is good approach. So you confirmed it. I try to use BitmapImage and compare memory usage results.

Comment: Nokia Imaging SDK is windows runtime only (wp8, wp8.1, windows 8.1)